# refetching a query with react-apollo: why is `loading` not true?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying Apollo and using the following relevant code:

```
const withQuery = graphql(gql`
query ApolloQuery {
  apolloQuery {
    data
  }
}
`);

export default withQuery(props => {
  const {
    data: { refetch, loading, apolloQuery },
  } = props;

  return (
        <p>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            onClick={async () => { await refetch(); }}
          >
            Refresh
          </Button>
          {loading ? 'Loading...' : apolloQuery.data}
        </p>
  );
});
```

The server delays for 500ms before sending a response with `` { data: `Hello ${new Date()}` } `` as the payload. When I'm clicking the button, I expect to see `Loading...`, but instead the component still says `Hello [date]` and rerenders half a second later.

According to [this](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-query-data-networkStatus), the `networkStatus` should be 4 (`refetch`), and thus `loading` should be true. Is my expectation wrong? Or is something regarding caching going on that is not mentioned in the React Apollo docs?

The project template I'm using uses SSR, so the initial query happens on the server; only refetching happens in the browser - just if that could make a difference.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think that you need to specify `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true` in the query options (it's `false` by default).

Comment: where to set this option?

Comment: @BryanLumbantobing you set this option here:
const { data, loading, refetch } = useQuery<
    InterfaceQuery
  >(
    UsersQuery({
      activeUser
    }),
    {
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true
    }
  );

Comment: Also if `skip` is true then even though `refetch` will be run explicitly, loading will remain false.